# Why won't my panel or programs bar appear

Tags: unity, panel

Whenever I boot into ubuntu, there is no panel or programs bar or even minimise, close or maximise controls. All I get is my desktop background. I have looked an numerous guides or help pages and there is nothing that appears to work.

Comment: Update your question with your Ubuntu version/arch. Also what is the output of `lspci | grep VGA` (try to open a terminal using Ctrl+Alt+T or Ctrl+Alt+F1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to lack of information (Ubuntu Version, Window Manager, believed cause of error, etc.) this is just a shot in the dark:

**NOTE: ~/.config holds a lot of other config; SO DO A BACKUP FIRST!**

It *could* be a broken gnome/unity config (assuming you use unity). You could try renaming your ~/.config folder

```
mv ~/.config ~/my_config_back
```

then logout and login again. The default config should load and provide you with an interface again. 
Happened to me once when playing with UnityTweak and CSSM at the same time.